# 3 tier server architecture with Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, 3-tier

Can Drupal be deployed on a 3 tier server architecture (Webserver/ Appserver/ Database)?

Our database tier will have MySQL. Which tier will drupal fit in and what should be used in the remaining tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

- **Application Tier** is basically a web node of your application. It would have a web server (Apache, Nginx) and Drupal running on it.
- **Data Tier** would be a database node with MySQL or MariaDB. You'd just provide its IP address in Drupal's `settings.php` file and it will just work. You may want to add an extra node for a shared file system you would mount to `/sites/default/files`.
- **Presentation Tier** is a tricky part. You may live without it (thus allowing Drupal's template system to handle the presentation - i.e. Application Tier would handle Presentation too). However, Drupal may be run "headless" - entirely as an API server, which gives you ability to write your own presentation logic (basically, an API client).

There are some interesting benefits of such a design: you may squeeze in some caching mechanism between Drupal and presentation thus eliminating Drupal's slowness. You may also easily scale Drupal instance horizontally by cloning web nodes. You may even shut down Drupal entirely for an update while presentation layer still serves cached content.

There are some interesting Headless / decoupled Drupal conference sessions out there:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GdpTwbmv0E
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FO6YdLQCX-w

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is, since Drupal is Open Source, you can do it, with a lot of work on your part, and you would effectively be creating your own forked version of Drupal, which you would then need to maintain, because Drupal's updates would no longer work for your version.

Drupal, Joomla, and other PHP/MySQL CMS solutions are designed to be installed on a single web server, without the separation between the presentation, business logic and data access tiers that would be necessary in a true 3 tier architecture.

This means they are very practical and easy to install and use for anyone with a typical web hosting solution, but it also means they are not adequate for your typical enterprise application handling private information that needs to be protected more thoroughly, and integrated with back office applications. (Although of course they are perfectly fine if that same enterprise just wants to have an information website).